# How to show google map with Latitude and Longtitude data from parse JSON?

Tags: android, google-maps

I already parse data json and got Latitude and Longtitude so then how to use them to show Google map? 
Any reference for that? Or sample code?

I just tried to search in google but I'm confused.

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: show how you searched. I don't believe such a simple question can confuse by searching.

Comment: you can use lat lng coordinates to place marker on the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

pass data using intent to your maps activity like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);  
i.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
i.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
i.putExtra("title", "title");
startActivity(i);
```

now retrive your data in your maps activity like this

```
Intent i = getIntent();
latitude = Double.valueOf(i.getStringExtra("latitude"))  
longitude = Double.valueOf(i.getStringExtra("longitude"));
title = i.getStringExtra("title");
```

now in your onMapReady method set lat long and title like this

```
 LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(title));
 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
 mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 14.0f));
```